# Testing repository for ConstraintViolationException in Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

I'm testing a repository in spring data using h2, the exact functionality I want to test for now is the constraint on one field length when the repository tries to save the entity.

For instance, the entity class looks something like this:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "page")
public class Page{

 @Id
 @Size(max=5)
 @Column(name="name")
 private String name;

 //... setters and getters.
```

From a service, I call the repository:

```
public class PageServiceImpl implements PageService{
 private PageRepository repository;

 public PageServiceImpl(PageRepository repository){
   this.repository = repository;
 }

 @Override
 public save(Page page){
   repository.save(page);
 }
}
```

The test for the service:

```
 @RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
 @DataJpaTest
 public class PageServiceImplIT{

 private PageService service;
 //...

   @Test
   public void shouldCrashWhenSaving(){
     Page page = new Page();
     page.setName("VeryLongString");
     service.save(page); // It should throw an Exception, Name is too 
                         // long
  }
//..
```

When I test the above code, passes succesfully, but I was expecting a ConstraintViolationException or some type of exception just like when I try to save the entity to a SQL database. What I am doing wrong?

**update**

I realized that if I try to get a list of the all registers in the database I get the exception:

```
   @Test
   public void shouldCrashWhenSaving(){
     Page page = new Page();
     page.setName("VeryLongString");
     service.save(page);
     List<Page> pages = service.findAll();//This causes the exception 
                                          //to be thrown.
  }
```

This is the first part of the stack trace:

```
  org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not execute statement
```

However what I am looking for is to get the exception as soon as the repository saves the entity.

Comment: Is a JSR-303 implementation available on the classpath? What happens if you run the test after changing `@Column(name = "name")` to `@Column(length = 5, name = "name")`?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I changed the Column annotation but it did not work. It seems that the exception is not thrown when it saves the entity.

Comment: I suspect that the changes are not been "flushed", which is why the validations are not kicking in. If your repository extends `JpaRepository`, could you try `saveAndFlush(page)` instead of `save(page)`? If not, could you try injecting a `TestEntityManager` as `@Autowired TestEntityManager entityManager` and then flushing it manually with `entityManager.flush()`?

Comment: Thanks you so much. Using saveAndFlush solved the problem. If you want, put your comment as an answer and I will accept it.